# Sockets and functions

Tags: python, sockets

I have a big question I couldn't get answer from the web about
sockets in python.
I'm making a simple client program (python) based on socket:
Connecting to a server.

I would like to make a function that its purpose is just to try to connect to the server, otherwise the application will not work.
Because I had trouble with "global" socket variable across the whole class, I decided to make a local socket variable inside my main and pass it through all functions.

I wanted to make sure that I understand it 100% :
Should I **return the socket from the function** that's trying to connect to the server ( otherwise sleeps for 0.5 a second and tries again )
**OR** I don't need to return the socket at all and the **socket variable itself will be updated** ?

**UPDATE**

```
#will try to connect to the server 
def try_connecting_to_server(socket_to_server):
    connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            socket_to_server.connect((HOST, PORT))  # connect to the server
            connected = True
        except:
            print "couldn't connect to server, sleeping for 0.5 seconds"
            time.sleep(0.5)

    return socket_to_server

def main():
    # start the socket to the server
    socket_to_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #                          setup the socket for future use
try:
    socket_to_server = try_connecting_to_server(socket_to_server)
    handle_missions(socket_to_server) # pass the socket
except:
    print "encountered an error"
finally:
    socket_to_server.sendall(PROTOCOL_CLOSE_KEY)
    socket_to_server.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Showing the code you're asking about would make it much easier to help, don't you think?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart , I'm sorry, updating my post right now.

Comment: function which executes only one function is useless - you could use `socket_to_server.connect()` directly in `main`

Comment: @furas , what I mean is that the try_connecting_to_server function will be a loop until the client is connected .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def try_connecting_to_server(socket_to_server):
    connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            socket_to_server.connect((HOST, PORT))  # connect to the server
            connected = True
        except:
            print "couldn't connect to server, sleeping for 0.5 seconds"
            time.sleep(0.5)

    return socket_to_server
```

There is no reason for this function to return `socket_to_server`.

Since a `socket` object is mutable, any changes to it inside the function (e.g. connecting it to a server) **are** visible to the function which called it.

You can verify that by making this change in `main()`:

```
returned_sock = try_connecting_to_server(socket_to_server)
if returned_sock is socket_to_server:
    print "They refer to the exact same object!"
```

See [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)